# Possible to animate dynamic height using CSS? JS alternatives accepted

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-animations

I'm using `AngularJS` which allows me to use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to show and hide elements based on a logical condition. What I'm trying to accomplish is to animate the size changes of the container when the children objects are shown-hidden so it's less jumpy.

For those not familiar with `AngularJS`, `ng-show` and `ng-hide` basically just applied the `display: none` and `display: block` properties. So when a container is set to `show` the display is set to `block`.

With that out of the way, I've been reading on animating height changes through a few pages of google searches and all I can find are examples using `max-height` to animate it from one height to another, which are statically defined by CSS rules, for example:

```
#animated-div {
    max-height: 100px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease;
}

#animated-div.hidden {
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

and they would remove the `.hidden` class to cause the transition to animate the change in height.

The issue is that I'm not opening/closing a container and there's no pre-determined height that the container will be, as the container can be modified dynamically based on a variety of variables. On-top of that the application is responsive, so the height will vary across devices.

Here is an example scenario:

```
- Container
  - Div A (Height: 200px); Shown
  - Div B (Height: 100px); Shown
  - Div C (Height: 300px); Hidden
  - Div Slider (Height: Dynamic) Hidden.
```

Currently the height of the container (which is `auto`) is `300px` based on the children, now the user toggles Div C active, which increases the height to `600px` The div should animate the expansion from `300px -> 600px` now the user clicked the `clear` button, the children of the container are all hidden, the container should animate from `600px -> 0px`.

The user then starts messing with a slider, which value ranges from `0 to 100`. This height is applied to the `Div Slider`. Say the user slides to 57. This should cause an animation from `0px -> 57px` as none of the divs are shown.

Sorry for the in-depth example of what I want, but it's the only way I can think to explain it. For reference, children in the container are scaled dynamically, using `%` values and `vw/vh` values. The size of the container when a certain combination of children are active is never the same across different resolutions, so this must be able to animate dynamic changes in height.

**Javascript examples are welcome, however for this project I do not wish to involve any additional libraries, Javascript examples must work on modern mobile browsers.**

Answer (score 0):

Your question got me thining for a while and in the end I came up with an interesting solution.

Instead of trying to animate the parent element - animate the new children instead.

I've created a [codepen here](http://codepen.io/wicek3d/full/WxOJZz/) that does exactly that. 
I'm using a CSS animation for both 'show' and 'hide' effects.

Here's a little LESS code for the main animations:

```
.parent{
  width:33%;
  overflow:hidden;
  .child{
    padding:.5rem;
    border:1px solid #78909C;
    border-bottom:0;
    color:#fff;
    animation:slideDown .2s ease-in forwards; //set basic "show" animation
    transform-origin:top center; // set proper transform origin
    &.removed{
        animation:slideUp .2s ease-in forwards; // add different animation for "hide"
    }
    &:nth-child(even){background:#78909C;}
    &:nth-child(odd){background:#546E7A;}
    &:last-child{border-bottom:1px solid #78909C;}
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this solves your issue perfectly, but it's definitely something that will help you out here.